# OnBlur validation before button click()

Tags: javascript

i like to know how to validate a text-field at it instant.when ever we move to another text field with out filling the above text-field we need to get an alert message using on-blur(). using java-script.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What's your progress?

Comment: take a look at html5 validation and the required attribute like my example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onblur()` event in javascript

```
<input type="text" onblur="test('firstTextBox')"/>

function test(value)
{
  if(value == "firstTextBox")  
  alert("This is blur");
  else if ....
  .....
}
```

Comment: thank you. can u help me out with a sample line of code how to use onblur() event for a text field

Comment: the above example is for textfield only.What is your doubt in that

Comment: if i'm using multiple textbox's how to mention it, b'coz each textbox will have it own message.so , at that place i need to have multiple functions or else any other alternate for it..

Comment: sorry i did not see your post before im posting my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have look into [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) and try the below code to work in `onblur`.

```
$('#field1, #field2, #field3').blur(function(){
    validator.validate()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.But, i like to know onblur() how to use it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use the html5 form validation take a look at `validity` property and set html 5 form attributes like required

html5:

```
<input type="number" required="true"  onfocus="setCustomValidity('Custom Message')" onblur="testit(this)"/>
```

js:

```
function testit(e){
    if(e.validity.valid == false){
        alert(e.validationMessage);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ANnf/2/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML (at bottom)